# Element with left side smaller and right side greater in C

Tags: arrays, c, data-structures

I'm very confused about the function implemented for the following code. What does the returning of 'i' mean? What is the exact logic behind it? If I do the dry run and return 'i', where is this 'i' getting returned to?

Given an array, find an element before which all elements are smaller than it, and after which all are greater than it. Return the index of the element if there is such an element, otherwise, return -1.

Input: arr[] = {5, 1, 4, 3, 6, 8, 10, 7, 9};

Output: 4

```
int SlideToTheLeft(int a[],int n){
int left[n], i;
left[0]=0;
for(i=1;i<n;i++){
    left[i]=Max(left[i-1],a[i-1]);
}
int right=100;
for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
    if(left[i]<a[i] && right>a[i]){
        return i;
    }
    right=Min(right,a[i]);
}
return -1;
}
```

Comment: Where is this `i` getting returned to? To the function that called this function. What does it mean? It's the array index that satisfies the condition mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first loop populates the "left" array. This array stores the largest value to the left of a given index. So for example, if left[3] is 7, we know that a[0], a[1], and a[2] are less than or equal to 7.

The second loop traverses the array from right to left, keeping track of the largest value to the right of the current index. We start with a value of right=100. This assumes that all values of a[] will be less than 100. We then traverse the array and update "right" if we encounter lower values of a[] than our current lowest. This is done in "right=Min(right,a[i]);".

Every time we go through the loop, we check for the condition where left[i]<a[i] (all indexes to the left are smaller than a[i], and right>a[i] (all indexes to the right are greater than a[i]. If we meet this condition, we return i (since this is the index which meets this condition).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Now, I'm getting the hang of it!